# how to remove space or tab character before insert to a table by reading another table using Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

I am reading a table and inserting data to another table using cursor. When there is a space or tab character in the source data I have below error? I had this error in the date field.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET(effectivestart_date  = cursor_rec.effectivestart_date)
WHERE columnA = cursor_rec.valueA;
```

And the error is :

```
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
```

This is because the `effectivestart_date` field in the source table has space instead `NULL`

Can someone help me how to remove space or tab before inserting?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET(effectivestart_date  = trim(cursor_rec.effectivestart_date))
WHERE columnA = cursor_rec.valueA;
```

However, I see a couple of issues with this approach - apparently, the effectivestart_date in your cursor is a varchar2 field, but the effectivestart_date in your table is of date datatype. You're not using to_date() to explicitly change your string into a date datatype - that way lies madness! Suppose someone comes along and changes the default nls_date_format setting?

The other issue is that you're presumably looping round the cursor and updating the table based on that. That's row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) processing. Why not do the whole thing in a single UPDATE or MERGE statement instead? It'll be easier to code, debug, maintain and faster to run.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the REPLACE function

for c in cursor_rec loop

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET(effectivestart_date  = REPLACE(c.effectivestart_date,' ','NULL')
WHERE columnA = cursor_rec.valueA;
```

end loop;

If the field effectivestart_date in your cursor is a varchar2, you need to convert to date.

```
TO_DATE(REPLACE(c.effectivestart_date,' ','/'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```